# Convert Object texture coordinates to UV

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, coordinates

I have an object which as a texture that is positioned using Object Texture Coordinates that uses an Empty as its positioning object. I want to convert this to a UV texture.

[image]

In Edit mode I press U > Project from view (bounds) but when I change the coordinates to UV the texture doesn't look right.

[image]

Is there any way to convert from Object texture coordinates to UV and preserve how it looks?

Comment: Do you creating UV exactly from the view point of Empty? From the images it looks like a random angle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use baking.

1. In the UV Editor create a new image (called Baker on my pic)
2. Create your material in the Shader Editor
3. Add a new image texture node in Shader Editor. Click on the browse icon and find an image on your computer
4. With the image texture node active, switch to the Render tab and go the Bake settings. Under Bake Type choose Diffuse and under Influence select only color, then hit on Bake.
5. Save the new texture file.
6. Change the material's texture image to the baked.
   [image]

Comment: That's the correct procedure.

Comment: Marking this as the answer but it would still go be good to be able to do without baking so that I can still move around the textures at a later time